# how can i completely remove gnome3 from ubuntu 20.04 without affecting KDE Plasma

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde, 20.04

Plaease help on how can i completely remove gnome3 from ubuntu 20.04 without affectind KDE Plasma because i have limited space. Thank you. I have only found maretials for removing KDE and none for gnome.
here
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374638/how-do-i-completely-remove-gnome-from-ubuntu-desktop-after-installing-kde#:~:text=Your%20best%20path%20is%20to,what%20you're%20asking%20for.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374638/how-do-i-completely-remove-gnome-from-ubuntu-desktop-after-installing-kde#:%7E:text=Your%20best%20path%20is%20to,what%20you%27re%20asking%20for.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way that you should start with would be installing `kubuntu-desktop` metapackage, removing `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage and performing `sudo apt autoremove --purge` after reading through packages that will be removed and verifying that you don't need any of them.

However if you have limited space you can remove more packages that you don't need and that action may remove `kubuntu-desktop` in the process. At that point you need to mark some packages as installed manually to avoid removing them when you perform `autoremove`. You can do it either with [apt-mark](https://askubuntu.com/a/149780/20275) or just by performing `apt install packagename`.

Another, less safe way would be finding a package that all GNOME software depends on and removing it so that it will take all the packages that depend on it with it. `libgnome-desktop-3-*` looks like a candidate package for that. Be careful around `libgtk*` packages though as it may be too excessive, `kde-config-gtk-style` and `kde-config-gtk-style-preview` depend on it.

Before starting you can backup lists of installed packages with `apt-mark showmanual` and `apt-mark showauto`.