# How do I completely remove GNOME from Ubuntu Desktop after installing KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde

Today I reinstalled Ubuntu Desktop with GNOME and then I installed KDE.  I want to remove GNOME completely as if it never existed.  I have been scouring the internet for the past hour and I can't find a solution to fully remove GNOME.  I have installed KDE and there are no other packages other than prebuilt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) . Use search directly on AskUbuntu next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing desktop environments on an installed system can be **messy**. This is why most distros, including Ubuntu, publish several versions of the OS with different desktop environments.

Installing Ubuntu with GNOME was not a good decision if you want Ubuntu with KDE "as if GNOME never existed". If you want to continue with your current installation, it will be more difficult and time consuming than it would be to just reinstall the correct flavor.  Also, you may have a difficult time removing GNOME without additional side effects like removing software you don't want to remove while still having remnants from GNOME that you don't want.

The official flavor of Ubuntu with KDE is [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org). Your best path is to just reinstall Kubuntu if you want to use Ubuntu with KDE.  In this case GNOME would have never existed on your installation, which is exactly what you're asking for.